# A first chance exception of type 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am newbie in EmguCV and when I try to use `GPUInvoke.SwapChannel` and `GPU.Convolution` I get:

> A first chance exception of type 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred
>   in Emgu.CV.dll

This is my code

```
Image<Rgb, Byte> img = new Image<Rgb, byte>(StringA);
GpuImage<Rgb, Byte> gpi = new GpuImage<Rgb, byte>(img);
int[] a = new int[4];
a[0] = 4;
a[1] = 3;
a[2] = 2;
a[3] = 1;
GpuInvoke.SwapChannels(gpi, a, IntPtr.Zero);
Image<Rgb, Byte> im = gpi.ToImage();
pictureBox2.Image = im.ToBitmap();
```

and this

```
Image<Rgb, Single> img = new Image<Rgb, Single>(StringA);
GpuImage<Rgb, Single> gpi = new GpuImage<Rgb, Single>(img);
float[,] k = {{1,2,3,1,2},
              {2,4,5,4,2},
              {3,5,6,5,3},
              {2,4,5,4,2},
              {1,2,3,2,1}};
ConvolutionKernelF kernel = new ConvolutionKernelF(k);
GpuImage<Rgb, Single> gp = gpi.Convolution(kernel, new Emgu.CV.GPU.Stream());
Image<Rgb, Single> im = gp.ToImage();
pictureBox2.Image = im.ToBitmap();
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: GpuInvoke.SwapChannels(gpi, a, IntPtr.Zero); and GpuImage<Rgb, Single> gp = gpi.Convolution(kernel, new Emgu.CV.GPU.Stream());

Comment: Read this. What is a first chance exception ? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx

Comment: i already solved it thanks all